# Joining two relations with default values

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sqlplus

I have two views:

```
view1   view2
obj    obj attribute
+-+     +-+--+
|A|     |C|27|
+-+     +-+--+
|B|
+-+
|C|
+-+
```

How can I combine the values and return the output,

```
obj attribute
 +-+--+
 |A| 0|
 +-+--+
 |B| 0|
 +-+--+
 |C|27|
 +-+--+
```

with 0's as default values in SQL? I don't want to use PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT v1.obj, NVL(v2.attribute, 0)
FROM view1 v1
LEFT JOIN view2 v2 on v1.obj = v2.obj
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what `NVL()` does, but does Oracle also support the standard `COALESCE()` function?

Comment: Given that I was fairly sure that Oracle _did_ support the ANSI-Standard `COALESCE()` function, the purpose of my question was to get _you_ to think about it, not to fill a gap in _my_ knowledge.

Comment: @X-Zero - Sorry, to me it looked (and still looks) like a question you wanted an answer to, not something I was supposed to go off and ponder.

Comment: @dcp - Hmm, I guess I should have tweaked it a little more to point the answerer in that direction.